# SharePoint 2019 SPFx, react-router-dom and its types

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfx-webparts, 2019, react

I am using SharePoint 2019 on premise. When I latest react-router-dom and its type I get error for type. Below is my dependencies

[image]

and my "typescript": "~2.4.1"

So somebody help me which version of react-router-dom and its @types I should use in my project

Comment: Please any help on this ?